# Get the URL from C# script used in ssis

Tags: c#, ssis, azure-data-factory

In ssis package , there is a c# dynamic script. i want to use that in adf.

In ssis package , there is a c# dynamic script. i want to use that in adf. But am not getting where and how to find the URL ? Can anyone help me.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/script-task?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: get value back (there are examples too) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/returning-results-from-the-script-task?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Questions about code that show no code are impossible to answer. Please click the Edit link on your question and add in the code from the Script Task/Component

Comment: There is no way to know how to help without any code. And even with the code, we still might not be able to help without a better question.